# Why isn't my Rspec Feature test using Capybara to add an item to the test database collection?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec, capybara

I have a page in my app for Sales_Opportunities. These have_many Timeline_Events, which can be added via a Bootstrap modal on the Sales_Opportunity page. It actually works in the real-world app (using the localhost server on my machine I can get the feature working), but the test itself does not - and when I use Byebug it's clear the sales_opportunity.timeline_events array is empty.

My Sales Opportunity Spec:

```
describe 'the Sales Opportunity view', :type => :feature do
  let(:company) {FactoryGirl.create(:company, :with_users)}
  let(:user) {company.organization.users.first}
  let!(:sales_opportunity) { FactoryGirl.create(:sales_opportunity, user: user, company: company )}

  describe 'the Sales Opportunity details view' do
    before(:each) do
      sign_in user
      visit sales_opportunity_path(sales_opportunity)
    end

    it 'has links to add a timeline event' do
      expect(page).to have_link('Add new task')
    end

    it 'adds a new timeline event', js: true do
      page.click_link('Add new task')
      sleep 1
      page.find('#timeline-event_modal').fill_in('Activity', with: "Sign the contract")
      page.find('#timeline-event_modal').fill_in('Due date', with: "2014/10/15")
      page.find('#timeline-event_modal').check "Completed"
      page.find('#timeline-event_modal').fill_in('timeline_event_event_notes', with: "Some example notes")
      page.find('#timeline-event_modal').click_button('Save')
      expect(current_path).to eq(sales_opportunity_path(sales_opportunity))
      byebug
      expect(page).to have_content('Sign the contract')
      expect(page).to have_content('2014-10-15')
      expect(page).to have_content('Yes')
      expect(page).to have_content('Some example notes')
    end
  end
```

Factory girl code (Company):

```
FactoryGirl.define do
  factory :company do
    company_name            "Test Company"
    existing_customer       "False"

    trait :with_users do
      association           :organization, :with_users
    end 
  end
end
```

Factory (Organization):

```
FactoryGirl.define do
  sequence(:organization_name) { |n| "Organization - #{n}" }

  factory :organization do
    organization_name { generate(:organization_name) }

    trait :with_users do
      before(:create) do |organization|
        organization.users << FactoryGirl.build(:user)
        organization.users << FactoryGirl.build(:user, name: "Second User", email: "email2@example.com")
      end
    end
  end
end
```

Factory for Sales Opportunity:

```
FactoryGirl.define do
  sequence(:opportunity_name)    { |n| "Sales Oppotunity - #{n}" }

  factory :sales_opportunity do
    user
    opportunity_name     { generate(:opportunity_name) }
    close_date           "2014/12/12"
    sale_value           10000
    company_id           7
  end
end
```

I can include the Controller and View code if it helps, but as mentioned the code actually works in the app on the development server (timeline event is updated and inserted into a table on the sales_opportunity show page) so it's something to do with the way I've set up my tests, set up my factories, or my misunderstanding of the way this works.

For reference I have other code that works exactly the same way on other views, with factories and rspec tests that give positive results.

Byebug output from the break above:

```
(byebug) sales_opportunity
#<SalesOpportunity id: 2535, close_date: "2014-12-12 00:00:00", user_id: 22124, created_at: "2015-07-29 12:06:35", updated_at: "2015-07-29 12:06:35", pipeline_status: 0, opportunity_name: "Sales Oppotunity - 15", company_id: 7650, sale_value: #<BigDecimal:7ffbbfe2e7b8,'0.1E5',9(27)>, swot_score: 0>

(byebug) company
#<Company id: 7650, company_name: "Test Company", existing_customer: false, created_at: "2015-07-29 12:06:35", updated_at: "2015-07-29 12:06:35", organization_id: 34613>

(byebug) sales_opportunity.timeline_events
#<ActiveRecord::Associations::CollectionProxy []>

(byebug) user
#<User id: 22124, name: "Test user 124", email: "test.user124@example.com", created_at: "2015-07-29 12:06:35", updated_at: "2015-07-29 12:06:35", password_digest: "$2a$04$bRkyvW1g9NtC9x4Skyicme6YDUUxDxA6Eg2iPoT9Xsy...", organization_id: 34613, remember_token: "47307ea19e1a63cf2ebdcc6a2cf8f763aef1561b", admin: false, password_reset_token: nil, password_reset_sent_at: nil>
```

I get the following error from the rspec run:

```
Failure/Error: expect(page).to have_content('Sign the contract')
Rspec then lists the items on my page until the timeline_events table:
No data available in table Showing 0 to 0 of 0
```

So it's clear that the array is still empty once the "Save" button is clicked and we return to the sales_opportunity page in the test suite.

Any idea what I'm doing wrong or how I could clean up my Factories/tests to get this working? Or is there another alternative way to ensure the functionality works without this type of test?

Comment: (1) Given by your first paragraph, classes in Ruby are UpperCamelCase. (2) It looks like you are repeating yourself in your test. Try doing `within '#timeline-event_modal' do`, followed by the related events (fill_in, check). (3) When using Capybara, you should not need to use `sleep 1`. Instead, try something like `wait: 3`. The default wait time is 2 seconds. Only some methods accept the `wait` option.

Comment: Thanks. I if use `wait: 3` I get a syntax error, the code is expecting an `end`. If I use `wait 3` then the Rspec test says it's an undefined method. I use sleep effectively in other Capybara tests like this, and it was originally failing without that (i.e. it wasn't waiting for the Modal to appear and was missing the content). `Sleep 1` is long enough for the fields to appear and those element.find tests to pass.

Comment: Like I said, the `wait` option does not apply to all Capybara methods. I use it, for example, when doing `page.accept_confirm(wait: 3) { click_link 'Delete' }` to click a delete link that triggers a modal that asks "are you sure?" When using capybara for feature tests, you may find it helpful to use its DSL to the max, like using `scenario` to mark each example. I recommend reading up on the Github page docs more, too

Comment: Thanks for the assistance. Any ideas why my factories/test DB won't accept the newly inserted timeline_event in this case? I was having a similar issue with the model spec, and my factory was the issue there (I needed to call sales_opportunity.reload to get that working) so I get the impression that these Factories don't work well when recycled through multiple tests. (BTW, sales_opportunity.reload doesn't work here).

Comment: Unfortunately I cannot help that much further. You may want to read documentation on all related gems/technologies before proceeding?

Comment: No problem, I appreciate your help, especially with the DRYing up of my code (which is almost certainly its biggest weakness). I'll find the answer somehow, it's just annoying when you hit a day-long brick wall like this and are trying to learn it on your own.

Comment: I suggest visiting the Ruby chat room for any additional help. They are great !

Comment: If the timeline_events is empty it would imply that either the form isn't submitting or its failing validations when attempting to save -- what do your test logs show as far as the submission after 'Save' is pressed?  - Note that your expect(current_path).to eq(sales_opportunity_path(sales_opportunity)) line isn't actually doing anything since you're on that path when you click 'Save' and the expectation doesn't wait for anything so it can possibly be executed before the 'Save' click causes any change to the url

Comment: Thanks Tom - you're right, for some reason the Activity field is being found by Capybara, but the 'Sign the contract' text is not being passed through to the controller. I'll see whether I can work out why this is happening. Do you have a solution for the path expectation test? Could I test for whether or not the server responds successfully to the AJAX call?

Comment: Tom - fantastic; I solved the problem by being more specific with the Capybara targeting of DOM elements. Thanks for your help - if you want to add that as an answer I'd be happy to select it as the solution. Cheers!